# Redirecting to a static view when no id is provided in url in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm pretty new to MVC and routing is a bit confusing.  I have the beginnings of an app that routes properly based on the url when it has an id, ala "~/events/12345"

However, what I need is for it to redirect to another view (about.cshtml) when a user simply leaves off the trailing id at the end of the url.

When I do this, it displays a 404 error, even though I have a CustomErrors tag redirecting to this About view in my app.  When I enter an INVALID id, it redirects, but if I leave the ID blank, it shows a 404.

I tried a few custom routes but so far am not getting anything to work.  Can anyone shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

investigate `this.ViewContext.RouteData` this will allow you to check if the parameter ('12345') is present.